# Mute/unmute iframe video from another domain

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I've implemented an iframe inside my webpage, the iframe points to another domain to catch the video content.

Nothing fancy inside my webpage, the iframe is standard aswell:

```
<iframe id='frame' src='domain.com/stream/324/index.m3u8' width='100%' allow='autoplay; encrypted media' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I would like to add buttons **outside the iframe to mute or unmute the video**, even though the presence of the player's controllers.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `<iframe>` tag for videos. Instead, use the HTML5 [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) tag. With a `<video>` tag you can set the `muted` attribute. You can rewrite your `<iframe>` like this:

```
<video id="video" controls width="100%" src="domain.com/stream/324/index.m3u8"></video>
```

You can then create a button and add an event listener to mute and unmute the `<video>` tag. Like this:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('video').muted = true">Mute</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('video').muted = false">Unmute</button>
```